# Deploy 32 or 64 bit Linux as Host machine for embedded development

Tags: linux, embedded, host

Of course my target Linux is running on a 32 bit MCU. So are there any restrictions if my host environment is running on a 64 bit system?

Or should I just take the 32bit host version and not care about the 64 bit version. I mean the only thing I am doing is build applications for my embedded device. Or are there any speed advantages on a 64 bit host system regarding GCC compilation, QT programming , etc...

What is your personal point of view on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically,
 no real change happens.

But, from my personal experience, you may encounter problems if you have to copy the development environment to another computer and you don't want to do a complete setup (for example: a broken host, or having to do maintenance after several months to the code, possibly not done by the same author of the original code and/or nobody remembers how they did the setup when the development was started). Using a 64 bits limits this "portability". For now there are multiarch distributions like Debian, you can face even more problems if you need to quickly set up another machine.

This is why I ended with using virtual machines running 32 bits GNU/Linux: if you need to quickly setup a new computer, just copy a bunch of files, make sure you have virtualbox or vmware installed on the new pc and you're almost done.